# Multiple Where clauses in Lambda expressions from different classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have created a main class called **AppRequest**, and under that, there are other classes **Suspense**,**SuspenseDetails**.
When I querying data, I want to query it one from **AppRequest**, one from **Suspense** and one from the **SuspenseDetails**.

This is how write the code

```
int y = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
List<AppRequest> SuspencesforSettle = db.AppRequest.Where(s => s.Create_By == y).Where(s=> s.Status==true).ToList();
```

I want to query from **AppRequest** - CreatedBy and Status and also need to check Settle_Status from the **SuspenseDetails**.
But, from the where condition I only can get the fields under the **AppRequest** class only. Can you guys help me to solve this?

This is how my Model designed.

```
 public class AppRequest
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
        public int ReqType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requesting By")]
        public int Req_By { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requesting Date")]
        public DateTime Req_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Location")]
        public int Req_Location { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Heading")]
        public string Req_Heading { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cover Note")]
        public string Req_CoverNote { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public int Company_Id { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public int Create_By { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
        public int Modified_By { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int Approval_Status { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Suspense> Suspense { get; set; }
     }

 public class Suspense
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("AppRequest")]
        public int Req_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual AppRequest AppRequest { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<SuspenseDetails> SuspenseDetails { get; set; }
    }

 public class SuspenseDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Suspense")]
        public int Sus_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Suspense Suspense { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requesting Amount")]
        public decimal Req_Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Amount In Words")]
        public string Req_Amount_In_Words { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Purpose")]
        public string Purpose { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cash Requesting for ")]
        public int Req_For { get; set; }

        public string Approved_Suspense_Id { get; set; }
        public bool Cash_Issued { get; set; }
        public int Cash_IssuedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Cash_Issued_Date { get; set; }
        public bool Settled { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```cs
var result =
    db
        .AppRequest
        .Where(appRequest => appRequest.Create_By == creator)
        .Where(
            appRequest =>
            appRequest
                .Suspense
                .SelectMany(suspense => suspense.SuspenseDetails)
                .Any(suspenseDetails => suspenseDetails.Settled)
        )
        .ToList();
```